# BackUp sqlite db from UWP app to One drive

Tags: c#, sqlite, uwp, onedrive

I have an UWP app and want to backup it's database to One drive actually I'm using sqlite for UWP with EF7 RC1.

All I want is a copy from my database to OneDrive to sync it between devices but i'm totally lost, Can't find the database on my win10 mobile.

What is the .db location on my W10 mobile?
Wich one is the best OneDrive API's for W10 ? 
There is a sample where i can read some info ?

Comment: So have you found your database file with the provided code ?

Answer (score 1):

Your database should be in your application **local storage**.

On desktop, to find it, In Visual Studio, open your *Package.appxmanifest* file, open the *Packaging tab* and copy the package name.

Open your file explorer, navigate to the folder *C:\Users\**userName**\AppData\Local\Packages*. (don't forget to replace *userName* by your real user name. Then search for folder containing your package name.

If you open the folder *LocalState* you should find your database file.

[image: LocalStorage sample]

To access it through code (will work on phone also):

```
var folder = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
var files = await folder.GetFilesAsync();
var dbFile = files.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == "myDatabase.db");
```

If your database is created before your application deployment, your database will be deployed in your application install folder: to find it use `var folder = Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation;`

For **OneDrive API**, you have some samples there:

- https://github.com/OneDrive/onedrive-sdk-csharp/tree/master/samples/OneDriveApiBrowser
- https://github.com/OneDrive/onedrive-sdk-csharp/tree/master/samples/OneDrivePhotoBrowser

Comment: Yes, but you can't browse it with a file explorer. Just add the code that looks into localFolder or installationFolder into your MainPage `OnNavigatedTo` method and after the `folder.GetFilesAsync`, simply display all file names. You should be able to find your database. I have tested with the following initialization code in my dbContext file:  `protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlite("Filename=Blogging.db");
        }`